# Google play get list of subscription list

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

Is there a Google play API that can list all the subscriptions for an app?

I am not looking for purchases by a single user but as an admin I want a list of all subscription purchases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a function regarding that. But you can view it using their the Play Console dashboard as stated in this [document](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7391949?hl=en):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No, you should call getSkuDetails instead and provide Play a list of subscription skuIds. It will return available skuIds (with price and other info) to you.